# What's the name of this bounding box in Chrome Developer's Tool?

Tags: google-chrome

I'm trying to get some information on this purple border. Can you suggest me where to start from?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the mobile viewport. It is shown when you try to [Simulate mobile devices with Device Mode](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/device-mode/) and click on "Device Toggle Toolbar".

[image]